# How to list all the containers in an azure storage account (in C#, azure version 12.x)

Tags: list, azure, asynchronous, containers

I can only find deprecated version using CloudBlobClient. I have code like below,

```
                DataLakeServiceClient datalakeServiceClient = GetDSClient(connectionString);
                AsyncPageable<FileSystemItem> fsItems = datalakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemAsync(FileSystemTraits.Metadata);
                // how to deal with it now? for some reason, I cannot use await foreach yet
```

Thanks,
gohawks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason, I cannot use await foreach yet

`await foreach` is in C# 8.0, so check your project file. You should be able to [enable it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) by doing

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```